# When do you need the Windows SDK for MSBuild?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, msbuild, continuous-integration, winapi

I'm setting up my first build server for .NET 3.5 projects, and found this interesting line in the MSBuild log after a successful build of a simple test application:

> Could not locate the expected version
>   of the Microsoft Windows SDK. Looked
>   for a location specified in the
>   "InstallationFolder" value of the
>   registry key
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A". If your build
>   process does not need the SDK then
>   this can be ignored.

When exactly would your build process need the SDK? I don't want to install it on the build server if it's not going to be necessary, but I also don't want to discover that I need it by having a build mysteriously break.

At the moment, I only have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed on the server.

Comment: The SDK can be got from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsserver/dd146047.aspx, but make sure you choose the websetup version if you don't want to download the whole lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK has a couple of additional tools that are **sometimes** used, depending on the contents of your project - such as (IIRC) the reports compiler. But for most things, no: you don't need the SDK. I installed in on my build server just to get clean output ;-p

Answer (score 2):

If you need to compile C or C++ code - to the best of my knowledge.